# How to solve this error: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,786432], In[1]: [784,512] [[{{node MatMul}}]]>

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I need to do this simple machine learning code for  my school project but after many alterations I kept getting this error of invalid array. Can someone help? I'm quite desperate now as my submission date is close...

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras
test_image = image.load_img('Number 8.jpg')
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image, data_format='channels_first', 
dtype='float32')
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
result = model.predict(test_image)
print(np.argmax(result[0]))
```

Comment: What line gives the error? I was able to run this code without error up until `test_image = image.load_img('Number 8.jpg')` where it fails since I don't have the image 'Number 8.jpg'. Is this image the right resolution for mnist (28x28)?

Answer (score 0):

As tomkot already pointed out, its a shape problem.

The MNIST comes in shape [60000, 28, 28] and that's also the shape you train your model with.

I did a test with a Picture of my own and the shape that was passed to the predict was [1, 3, 1728, 2304].
This might differ in size from your 'Number 8.jpg' but as you can see will every picture being send with the wrong shape.

When you bring your picture in the shape that you trained your model with, your prediction should work just fine.

one way to reshape

```
# load your image
test_image = test_image.resize((28, 28), resample=Image.BICUBIC))
#resize your image
test_image = test_image.resize((28,28), resample=Image.BICUBIC)
#on the prediction call reshape
result = model.predict(test_image.reshape(-1,28,28))
```

the '-1' is another form to tell how many data your array contains.
You can also write it like '.reshape(1,28,28)'. '-1' just leaves it to python itself to figure out the proper value.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I'm new to this sorry if I could as how do you reshape the image? I tried using numpy.reshape but it doesn't work